# import "algo" from 'directorio-padre/miarchivo.js"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs

Necesito importar mi archivo db.js de un directorio superior, no sé cómo hacrlo y no hallo información en Internet. Lo que quiero es algo así:

```
import db from './db'
```

Comment: te refieres a salir de el directorio tipo aso: `import db from './../db.js'`

Comment: Gracias. Creo que si. Yo probe con '@/'  y me funcionó.